# ckeditor removes the textarea

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

On my website i have installed ckeditor, when i go into the folder and into the sample everything seems to be working just fine, but every textarea have been removed
example: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2ur11eb.jpg
on my site if i try to use ckeditor it just removes the textarea there too.

ive downloaded a custom ckeditor
 -Full preset
 -allmedias (plugin)
 -image uploader (plugin)
 -media (oEmbed) plugin (plugin)
 -moono dark color
 -english and danish
downloaded it as source (big n'slow) i have tried the optimized version too (gave the same resault)

Answer (score 0):

Are there some errors shown in browsers developers tools?

All you have to do to run CKEditor on your site is:

- unzip CKEditor files and put it on your sites folder
- put in `body` line: `<script src="your/ckeditor/path/ckeditor.js"></script>`
- put `<textarea id='editor'></textarea>` on your site
- replace `<script>` code, in this case
   CKEDITOR.replace('editor');

CKEditor should then replace the `<textarea>` field as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Download again CKEditor without those extra plugins.

There's at least one uploader "plugin" that it's available since sometime in the plugins repository and despite all the complains that it leads to broken CKEditor builds nothing has been done.